# MySQL syntax using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax, many-to-many

I have the following tables in my MySQL db:

```
CREATE TABLES Films (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),   
Title VARCHAR(255)),  

CREATE TABLE Genres (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
PRIMARY KEY(id),  
Name VARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE Films_Genres (
film_id INT NOT NULL,  
genre_id INT NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (film_id,genre_id),  
FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Genres(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE)";
```

I want to search for Films with specific Genre stored with `$genre`. I also want to select the name of this genre (dont ask my why ;) ). I know how to do the first part. Im trying to achieve the second part with `JOIN` but something is wrong with my syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM Films WHERE id IN (    
SELECT film_id FROM Films_Genres  
WHERE genre_id IN SELECT id FROM Genres WHERE Name = '$genre'))  
JOIN Genres ON Name = '$genre'
```

Error message: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN Genres ON Name = 'Action'' at line 1`

Comment: You need to name sub queries. `select * from (select id from t) x`

Comment: Try indenting your SQL. I tried it and couldn't - because you didn't have valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be written this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Films 
JOIN Genres ON id = genre_id
WHERE id IN 
(    
   SELECT film_id 
   FROM Films_Genres  
   WHERE genre_id IN (SELECT id FROM Genres WHERE Name = '$genre')
)   
AND Name = '$genre';
```

`JOIN` should be after `FROM`.

Or you can `JOIN` the tables directly instead of these `IN` predicates:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Films AS f
INNER JOIN Films_Genres AS fg ON f.id = fg.film_id
INNER JOIN Genres       AS g  ON g.id = fg.genre_id

WHERE g.Name = '$genre'
```

Comment: The last line should be g.Name I believe :). Great! Thanks @Mahmoud!